# View binary image assembly

Tags: debugging, assemblies, binary

I have a binary image (a dll) which I wish to view the assembly for.  I also have the PDB associated with the dll.

Are there any tools out there that will allow me to open the binary image and navigate through the assembly, without needing to execute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unmanaged binaries... if you have Visual Studio installed, then you can launch a VS Command Prompt, "cd" to the directory that contains both the DLL/EXE and its corresponding PDB, and run:

```
link.exe /dump /disasm mybinary.dll
```

That should dump the instructions in the binary (and all labels present in the PDB), decoded into assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about .Net, then [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is the tool you need.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  These are unmanaged, x86 binaries.